# Python macros, NSMALLPOSINTS vs NSMALLNEGINTS

Tags: python

How `NSMALLPOSINTS`, `NSMALLNEGINTS` macros are used in python? 
Is `nsmallnegint` is in the range -5 to 0 and `nsmallposint` is in the 0 to 256 range?

**EDIT:** 
I am still unclear why `NSMALLPOSINTS`, `NSMALLNEGINTS` have those values.

Comment: When asking questions like this, you should really try to give more context.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question: those values are used, because they are most used integers!

To better understand how `NSMALLPOSINTS` and `NSMALLNEGINTS` work:

It is actually an array of 262 integers (most commonly used). And this structure is basically used to access these integers fast. They get allocated right when you initialize your `NSMALLPOSINTS` and `NSMALLNEGINTS`.

```
#define NSMALLPOSINTS           257
#define NSMALLNEGINTS           5
```

Comment: Yes, this is the issue where it was discussed to extend from [0,100] to [-5,256] : https://bugs.python.org/issue1436243
Related question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that the range is from -5 (inclusive) to 257 (non-inclusive). 
In the source code for the Python int object, there are macros defined called NSMALLPOSINTS and NSMALLNEGINTS.

[Python source code for NSMALLPOSINTS and NSMALLNEGINTs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p4DUU.png)

It turns out Python keeps an array of integer objects for “all integers between -5 and 256”. When we create an int in that range, we’re actually just getting a reference to the existing object in memory.

If we set x = 42, we are actually performing a search in the integer block for the value in the range -5 to +257. Once x falls out of the scope of this range, it will be garbage collected (destroyed) and be an entirely different object. The process of creating a new integer object and then destroying it immediately creates a lot of useless calculation cycles, so Python preallocated a range of commonly used integers.

Comment: If we assume we are using a CPython implementation of Python3 with default options how many int objects have been created and are still in memory when we  execute `print("I")` ?

Comment: @EkaterinaKalache What exactly do you mean? If that is the only statement in your source code, then `261`(`abs(-5) + 256`) integer objects exist in memory.

Comment: Thank you, Christian. It confirms that I understood it correctly.